# Can someone tell me why my found text might not be selected?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I'm trying to highlight my found word by selecting it but nothing is selected. Does anyone have an idea why ?

```
TextPointer start = m_TextPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(matchs[m_rangeIndex + i].Index);
TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(m_keyword.Trim().Length);
RichTextBoxForOpenText.Selection.Select(start, end);
```

XAML

```
  <RichTextBox 
            SelectionBrush="Red"
            AllowDrop="True" 
            x:Name="RichTextBoxForOpenText"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             />
```

Comment: Does the control need to have focus first?

Comment: It would be a cool thing to focus on what you have selected.

Comment: I'm so stupid, I tried focusing and it works.

Comment: we are all stupid at one time or another - good luck!

Comment: Thank you and good luck to you, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextPointer start = m_TextPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(matchs[m_rangeIndex + i].Index);
TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(m_keyword.Trim().Length);
RichTextBoxForOpenText.Focus();
RichTextBoxForOpenText.Selection.Select(start, end);
```

**The solution is that you have to focus the RichTextBox.
Thanks to JohnB for the solution.**